# printing with java in eclipse for arrays

Tags: java, eclipse

I am writing a very simple program in java with ***eclipse*** where i make an array of size of at max 5000, placing the array values equal to the index, and then print all the values with spaces in between on the same line.

This is the code that I wrote :

```
int arr[]=new int[num];
for(int i=0;i<num;i++)
    arr[i]=i;
for(int i=0;i<num;i++)
    System.out.print(arr[i] + " ");
```

It is working fine with command prompt, but when run on eclipse, the program terminates without displaying the result for a value of

```
num>1500
```

Why is this problem happening, and what is the fix for this?

Comment: What command you used at command prompt?

Comment: Does it works for a smaller amount like 100 or 200??

Comment: Please post an MCVE so the behavior can be reproduced.

Comment: Try This https://eclipse.org/subversive/documentation/preferences/pref_console.php change console output size

Comment: @A_N_Y_R yes, it's working fine for smaller inputs!!

Comment: @Masud simple what i use every other time :  java filename

Comment: @A_N_Y_R no, that wasn't helpful, do you have any other suggestion?

Comment: Try again with Fixed Width Console of very large number of characters (considering the number of spaces and digits). If it fails Have no other Idea.

Comment: @A_N_Y_R  no, that doesn't work either :(

Comment: Would you mind changing `System.out.print` to `System.out.println` .. Most probably the problem is with the Eclipse console output limit..

Comment: @user1354678 actually i need to print this thing is the same line, do you know how to change the console output limit?

Comment: `Window > Preferences > Run/Debug > Console` , then do appropriate changes in the that window..

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand what you mean, but first of all add curly brackets to your for loops and give a value to your int *num*, like this:

```
int num = 1500;
int arr[]=new int[num];
for(int i=0;i<num;i++){
    arr[i]=i;
}
for(int i=0;i<num;i++){
    System.out.print(arr[i] + " ");
}
```

Like this your program prints out 0 till 1500.
Hope this helped you out, if not let me know!